# Compile-time ceiling function, for literals, in C?

Tags: c, floating-point, compile-time, ceil, compile-time-constant

I have a C program which involves some floating-point literal that's defined by a macro. And - it just so happens that in a performance-critical part of the code, I need the ceiling of that floating-point number, as an integer (say, an `int`). Now, if it were an actual literal, then I would just manually take the ceiling and be done with it. But since it's a macro, I can't do that.

Naturally, `ceilf(MY_DOUBLE_LITERAL)` works, but - it's expensive. `(int)(MY_DOUBLE_LITERAL) + 1` will also work... except if the literal is itself an integer, in which case it will be wrong.

So, is there some way - preprocessor macros are fine - to obtain the ceiling of `MY_DOUBLE_LITERAL`, or alternatively to determine whether it is an integer or not?

Notes:

- I cannot perform the `ceil()` before the performance-critical part of the code, due to constraints I won't go into. Naturally if one can move computation outside of the performance-critical part or loop, that's always best, and thanks goes to @SpyrosK for mentioning that.
- C99 preferred.
- You may assume the literal is a double, i.e. a decimal number like 123.4 or an exponential-notation like 1.23e4.

Comment: [C11 generics](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1)?

Comment: @pmg: 1. How would those help? 2. What do you think of my answer?

Comment: `#define ceil_literal(X) _Generic((X), double: ceil, default: dummy_int)(X)`, but of course, not all C99 compilers support `_Generic`.

Comment: If it's floating-point literal, as you say, I'd think `ceilf(MY_DOUBLE_LITERAL)` would be [optimized just as well](https://godbolt.org/z/ejrvrcsrb).

Comment: @P.P: Make this an answer?

Comment: @einpoklum You might as well update yours if you like.

Comment: BTW, C does not define floating point literals - only string and compound literals.  It does define FP _constants_.

Answer (score 2):

If your literal fits nicely within the int representation range, you will often be able to rely on compiler optimizations. clang and gcc, for example, will go as far as simply optimizing `ceilf()` away when it's provided a literal, so `ceifl(MY_DOUBLE_LITERAL)` will result in a literal being used and no time wasted at run-time.

If somehow that doesn't work with your compiler, you could use:

```
int poor_mans_ceil(double x)
{
    return (int) x + ( ((double)(int) x < x) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

which should be "easier" for a compiler to optimize. You can see this happening on <kbd>[GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/556vM8csq)</kbd>.

Having said that - Some compilers in more exotic setting might fail to optimize both `ceil()` and the function above. Example: [NVIDIA's NVCC compiler for CUDA](https://godbolt.org/z/7ex5744ob).

Comment: To handle negative values as well, I suggest `(int) x + ( ((double)(int) x < x) ? 1 : 0)` -- or, as P.P suggested, just use `ceil`/`ceilf` which your compiler should be able to optimize away.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to statically store the rounded float macro literal in a const variable outside the critical part of the code and use the precomputed int const value in the critical part.
This will work as long as the float returned by the macro is always the same value.

Comment: Actually, in my case, this will not work, since all of the code I'm working on is the performance-critical part, for reasons I won't go into. I'll clarify this in the question and sorry for the bother.